# ajax/jquery $.get() is not a function am using jquery 3.0.1/chrome browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

//try to retrieve data from input text and send it to external php function and retrieve it again in index.php

```
   $(document).ready( function () { 
        $('#button').click(function($) {
            var string = $('#text').val();
            $.get('home.php',  {input: string} ,function(data) {
                $('#content').text(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of interest is:

```
$('#button').click(function($) {
```

The argument cannot be the $ sign but the event argument:

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
```

For details see [jQuery click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) documentation.

So the snippet is:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#button').click(function(e) {
    var string = $('#text').val();
    $.get('home.php',  {input: string} ,function(data) {
      //$('#content').text(data);
      console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('textStatus: ' +  textStatus + ' errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input id="text" type="text">
</form>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: the same issue $.get() is not a function , is it chrome browser issue ?! 
even i try to use load() function to load the external php page doesn't work  ?!

Comment: @MostafaEsmat try to execute my snippet in chorme and let me know. The error is up to the parameter of $('#button').click(function(e) {. Instead of $ you have to use e or event or another variable.

Comment: i tried the code on chrome,  the snippet throw error  and  the same issue $.get() is not a function on chrome

Comment: thanks for help , the issue was the jquery cdn , i checked it and it works fine